# Multi-page signup with Microsoft Entra External ID for Customers

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-entra-external-id

I am considering utilizing Microsoft Entra External ID for customers in my new project instead of Azure AD B2C which I have used previously, but I have a requirement that the sign up process should be split into multiple pages. This is achievable in AAD B2C with User Journey and Orchestration step element in xml definition of custom policy. Is this somehow achievable with Entra?

Answer (score 4):

Not currently, no. At the moment External ID for Customers only supports user flows and basic federation, so you can't yet customise the same way as your can with Azure AD B2C custom policies.